# Stuck with vertical text aligning in li

Tags: html, css

Trying to put menu text right in the middle. No luck so far, and people here proved to be very helpful. :)  text align center usually helps with most of the questions that came up here. Didn't help me though. What am i doing wrong?

```
<header>
<div id="navmenu">
<ul>
<li><a href="<?php echo get_settings('home'); ?>">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.wordpress.org">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</header>

#navmenu {
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    height:60px;
    width:836px;
}
#navmenu ul {
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0; 
    list-style-type: none; 
    list-style-image: none;
}
#navmenu li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left:1px;
    background-color:#3D3D3D;
    width:49%;
    height:40px;
    color:#FFF
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the text will always be on a single line, you can vertically align the text by making the `line-height` the same height as the container.

Add `line-height: 40px` to your li:

```
#navmenu li {
  ...
  line-height: 40px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try by giving `table-cell` (instead of `inline-block`) for `display` property for `#navmenu li` ?

I believe that will work.

Answer (score 0):

I quickly grabbed this snippet out of one of my css files.

This was used to create a top right corner nav bar.

```
ul {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    right: 35px;

}

ul li {
    display: inline;
    text-transform: lowercase;
    text-align: right;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

If you want to center the whole menu container, use position:relative, and than apply the margin:auto property. If you need to center the individual links, i hope giving width and text-align center will surely work, as it is a block. If not, you can always use padding-left and padding-right to achieve that. But the width of the menu items will be scaled according to it's content. One more thing, try giving pixels instead of percentage and check. Hope this helps you.